# I have errors in the code (pine script v5)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I made a simple code according to my simple knowledge and it was working at the beginning, but after a while it shows me errors in the code and it stops working

```
//@version=5
indicator("HiVolS")
hiVol = if volume >= ta.highest(volume, 3000)
    3000
else
    if volume >= ta.highest(volume, 2000)
        2000
    else
        if volume >= ta.highest(volume, 1000)
            1000
        else
            if volume >= ta.highest(volume, 500)
                500
            else
                if volume >= ta.highest(volume, 400)
                    400
                else
                    if volume >= ta.highest(volume, 300)
                        300
                    else
                        if volume >= ta.highest(volume, 200)
                            200
                        else
                            if volume >= ta.highest(volume, 100)
                                100
                            else
                                0 
plot(hiVol)
```

I tried writing the code again but maybe something is wrong and i miss it ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should evaluate ta.highest on each loop of the script, a working code example :

```
//@version=5
indicator("HiVolS")
Ta_Highest3000 = ta.highest(volume, 3000)
Ta_Highest2000 = ta.highest(volume, 2000)
Ta_Highest1000 = ta.highest(volume, 1000)
Ta_Highest500 = ta.highest(volume, 500)
Ta_Highest400 = ta.highest(volume, 400)
Ta_Highest300 = ta.highest(volume, 300)
Ta_Highest200 = ta.highest(volume, 200)
Ta_Highest100 = ta.highest(volume, 100)
hiVol = 0.0
if volume >= Ta_Highest3000
    hiVol := 3000
else if volume >= Ta_Highest2000
    hiVol := 2000
else if volume >= Ta_Highest1000
    hiVol := 1000
else if volume >= Ta_Highest500
    hiVol := 500
else if volume >= Ta_Highest400
    hiVol := 400
else if volume >= Ta_Highest300
    hiVol := 300
else if volume >= Ta_Highest200
    hiVol := 200
else if volume >= Ta_Highest100
    hiVol := 100
else
    hiVol :=  0 
plot(hiVol)
```